# Modify the output of search bar ( AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

i'm a beginner in AngularJS . I try to understand the example about Search Tab .

Code here : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_search_tab.htm

My question : As default , i want to hide the result of items in $scope.items of controller which  i used ng-repeat.

When i search in bar , only results which i want to seek can display on screen.

How can i do that ?

Comment: Try a ng-hide to hide the items until the search is not undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code in filter to this

```
app.filter('searchFor', function(){

// All filters must return a function. The first parameter
// is the data that is to be filtered, and the second is an
// argument that may be passed with a colon (searchFor:searchString)

return function(arr, searchString){

    var result = [];

    if(searchString){

        searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();

        // Using the forEach helper method to loop through the array
        angular.forEach(arr, function(item){

            if(item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
                result.push(item);
            }

        });
    }

    return result;
};

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-model with input, and then pipe the item in ngRepeat expression to the [built in angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), to have the behavior that you want.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Check this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/2VcNiqxOOGd7o6eveFrx?p=preview)